# Upload files to SharePoint Online using SPHttpClient in an spfx webpart with the corresponding column data

Tags: httpclient, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am able to upload file using SPHttpClient in an spfx webpart to a document library. But I am not sure how to add the corresponding column data associated with the document.

For example
candidate details with a resume. Resume would be document and the details like name, email, etc would be the corresponding details in a particular row of that document library

I have referred the below link to upload document. It would be helpful if someone can add the code to update the columns too
[Upload files to SharePoint Online using SPHttpClient in an spfx webpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116622/upload-files-to-sharepoint-online-using-sphttpclient-in-an-spfx-webpart)

Answer (score 0):

You need upload the file first and then update file item metadata(column values).

[PnP/PnPjs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/) is the most popular library used in SPFx and helpful for your requirement also.

```
sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("your site/PnpLibrary").files.add(myfile.name, myfile, true).then(f => {  
        console.log("File Uploaded");  
        f.file.getItem().then(item => {  
            item.update({  
                Title: "Metadata Updated"  
            }).then((myupdate) => {  
              console.log(myupdate);  
              console.log("Metadata Updated");  
            });  
        });  
    });
```

[demo thread here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/file-upload-and-metadata-updation-in-spfx-with-pnpjsreact)